# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'

Tags: typescript

I have an object declared and properties assigned like this:

```
const decoded = JSON.parse(nk.binaryToString(message.data));

const matchStateChanges = {
  humans: {},
  ball: {},
}

const { name } = decoded // string e.g. "Player1"
matchStateChanges.humans[name] = state.humans[name] // object type e.g. {pos: {12,13}}
```

But the compiler breaks with:

> $ npx tsc
>
> match_control.ts:145:7 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any'
> type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type
> '{}'. 145       matchStateChanges.humans[name] = state.humans[name]
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you declare `const matchStateChanges = { humans: {}, ball: {} }` then the type of `matchStateChanges.humans` is a literal `{}`. It doesn't have any properties in it to index, it's an empty object literal. If you meant something else, you'll have to annotate the types in one way or another.

Comment: Thanks. Pointed me in the right direction anyway. I've answered the post as everything seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
// Declare a custom interface to type the object
interface HumanObject {
  [index: string]: object
}

..

const humans: HumanObject = {}

// we'll build this up when we loop messages so we only transmit what's changed
const matchStateChanges = {
  humans,
  ball: {},
}
```